# How do I reload a page regularly with post data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have to reload a page with post data regularly.

Is it possible to do this from the client side?

Like when I manually hit the refresh button it asks me if I want to send post data.

Can I do this in an automatic manner? (normal JS or an extension perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the network inspector to figure out what data is in the POST, then you can use a content script

create a basic [manifest.json](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) with your [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "6.6.6",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "description": "b-good.pl",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*", // you might only need this for cross-domain ajax
    "http://*/*"   // but check yourself
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://target/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
}
```

and your [content.js](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post(url, data).done(function(drugs){
    $(body).html(drugs); // if you want drugs in your body
  });
}, how_often)
```

I think this should point you in the right direction.
(yes, I know jQuery is not necessary, but it's convenient and I'm not feeling like writing xhr by hand :)

Comment: but how do I make add a content script?

Comment: I have included links to chrome documentation for you. I think now you should have everything you need to code this. If not, there are freelancers for hire :-)